# What element do I manage to add more length & center a nav bar

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/RichardTargett/gq966x0x/

```css
.left-nav-box {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #0B88D2; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;   
    height: 1500px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 225px;
}

#logo-image {
    border: 2px solid #0B88D2;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

}
.left-nav-box ul {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 168px;
}

.left-nav-box ul li{
    border: 1px solid #0B88D2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #2B5772;
    font-family: 'segoe ui', 'lucida sans unicode', 'lucida grande',       lucida, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 168px;
}

.left-nav-box ul li:hover{
    border: 1px solid #0B88D2;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #0B88D2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #2B5772;
    font-family: 'segoe ui', 'lucida sans unicode', 'lucida grande',       lucida, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 168px;
}


.left-nav-box ul li:nth-child(1):hover {
border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  font-family: 'segoe ui', 'lucida sans unicode', 'lucida grande',       lucida, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #EE0060;

}
```

```html
<div class="left-nav-box">
       
        <img src="http://unawakened.net/images/intro.jpg" id="logo-image" width="198">

    <ul>
        <li>Record</li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Art & Media</li>
        <li>Archive</li>
        <li>Forums</li>
        <li>Social</li>
        <li>Sign Up</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
   
        
        
            </section>
```

That's my code. Im [new] to web design so please understand. My question;

What am I doing wrong. I want the nav boxes to be equal length as the logo. And there not.

Just adding a few more pixels to the left is the goal. it's the left nav bar of more code Im not showing. Should I show more? What can I do to not get downvoted
thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a few things to the CSS:

```
.left-nav-box ul{
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

and

```
.left-nav-box ul li{
  width: 201px;
}
```

Basically, the browser is using the `<ul>` tag and automatically putting in padding on the left, so you need to manually tell it to not do that, then adjust the `<li>` width accordingly.

Comment: Ahhhrgh!  Thanks too!

I chose this as the answer solver. But both you guys helped. Lets hope this stays in my head for now. 

Now onto this postioning predicament...

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about downvotes. Your question is fine! :)

The main problem was that the `<ul>` tag automatically adds left-padding to the underlying `<li>` elements.

In general, try do not repeat yourself so much in the code. For example, when you have styled a `li` element, you don't have to repeat the CSS that stays the same for the `li:hover` selector. Try to find patterns and exploit them. It's hard in the beginning, and it may seem easier to just copy and paste, but your life will get a lot easier after a while...

Here is somewhat cleaner [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gq966x0x/1/) with the li-elements aligned.

Comment: So your saying I can take out the CSS elements that aren't new, or being used differently, in the li:hover?

Thanks! I will look at your code. As a logic-impaired person, I find myself wondering why I wasn't a sailing instructor rather a web designer ;)

Comment: Haha, lots of logic involved in sailing actually ;). But yes, exactly, not every animal is a cow, but every cow is an animal - just like not every li is an li:hover, but every li:hover is also a li, so all your styling for the li elements hold for li:hover.

Comment: aqhhhh never heard that one before. ;)

Mind you I was a sailer in the carribean for 3 years. no joke. So this builds confidence.

Thnx guys

Comment: Quite the shift from sailing in the caribbean to styling html list elements ;). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Update following CSS

```
.left-nav-box ul{padding-left: 7px;}
.left-nav-box ul li{width: 200px;}
```

length of which element you want to increase?

Comment: I got the sizing right. It's fixt. I just have a logo thats on top of it now, which I am adding a newimage:hover element to, and this is causing more problems.

Wont make another stack out of it though, but if someone wants to PM me and school my ass. Go for it.

Back to the batcave!